# readlink -f not working on multiple files

Tags: shell, files, symlink

I tried to run `readlink -f` on multiple files by using `wildcard "*"`, but it evaluates other files as *operand*

### Command

```
readlink -f *log
```

### Output (desired)

```
/home/trail_1.log
/home/trail_2.log
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
I am using `tcsh` and `readlink` is only command I am aware to read path of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `realpath`:

```
% realpath *
/data/code/mdweb/Gemfile
/data/code/mdweb/Gemfile.lock
/data/code/mdweb/README.markdown
```

`realpath` is not POSIX. It is available by default on FreeBSD systems, and on *some* (but not all) Linux systems (but AFAIK can be installed as a package on most, if not all, Linux systems).
`realpath`'s behaviour might be different across implementations, so the above behaviour is *not guaranteed to work*. I've tested it on FreeBSD 10 & Arch Linux.

Comment: I already checked. I have no command like `realpath` and I have no prev-ledges to install it.

Comment: @JigarGandhi You can get a binary (or compile one) and drop it in `~/bin`, and add that to your `$PATH`. You don't need to install it system-wide.

Comment: GNU coreutils includes a `realpath` command, and Linux distributions are standardizing on that, but it's taking time. For example Debian's coreutils package only includes `realpath` since jessie (currently testing); in wheezy (stable) `realpath` is an optional package containing an older implementation.

Answer (score 3):

`readlink` only works with one file, you need a loop to do that:

```
for f in *; do
  readlink -f -- "$f"
done
```

Comment: is there any alternative to `for` loop? @cuongim

Comment: This is probably the cleanest and most readable solution, looping over files is a widely used pattern in shell scripting. If you want to work recursively or with complex predicates, you can always use `find . -exec readlink -f -- '{}' ';' `

Comment: Note that `readlink` isn't POSIX, for example on OSX `readlink -f` won't work (I happened to find this out the other day, I always thought that `readlink` was POSIX, for some reason).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Yes, of course. `readlink` on OSX is not GNU readlink - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html. On OSX, you can use `greadlink` from coreutils.